# Differentiate research-level questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, tags, content-level

"Research-level question" = looking for research level answers, citing articles, giving an overview of articles/subfield, instead of repeating textbook/Wikipedia type knowledge and basic clarification.

Comment: Here's an example: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79/

Comment: Frankly I read your example, by you, an did not know how to answer it. Simply because it seems to contain incorrect assumptions and you ask a question which is hard to answer precisely with out using a good deal of mathematical language. With no indication in your question that you will be able to understand that mathematical language it makes me weary of taking the time to answer it in detail.

Comment: I think research level questions will be self differentiated ...

Comment: Brings back memories of sci.physics and sci.physics.research.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't this be clear from the phrasing of the question?

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to differentiate? If you need a "research-level" answer, just state that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is implicit: Research level questions require research level answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just create a research-level tag then?

Comment: and then a [high-school-level]  tag?

Comment: Surely common sense means that what is not tagged research-level is below research level

Comment: is there a tag number limit here? if so then that would be a waste of a tag.

Comment: @Sean Tilson: Yes, only up to five tags are allowed, and [meta-tags such as this are frowned upon](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: I wouldn't say it would be a meta tag as such. Because it would help the question get answered. There are some people here who want the site to research level only. If a tag was introduced then they could just ignore all the untasted questions by filtering only the tagged questions effectively having 2 physics sites.

Comment: See the 2nd answer's first point of this question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/621/do-we-really-want-a-homework-tag