# Maybe add an indicator showing level of question

Tags: feature-request, questions, tags, content-level

There is an existing discussion/request for a system to tag or otherwise indicate level of questions:

[Can we have a level-of-question tag please?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/can-we-have-a-level-of-question-tag-please)

[Differentiate research-level questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/differentiate-research-level-questions)

The idea is that people answering or searching could use this to filter questions. The indicator could for example be a tag, or else some other thing which is a required ingredient and would be selected from a pull-down list. Here is a possible set of choices for such a list:

1. from zero to around early high school, including teaching of same
2. advanced high school or university (undergraduate), including teaching of same
3. graduate study to open research question

With this post I am re-asserting the existing request(s). It is true that the level of most questions becomes clear early on when reading the question, but a tag would help people wanting (3) to avoid looking at (1) altogether, and *vice-versa*. The choice of tag need not be checked by the system; if someone picked the wrong tag then they would simply reduce the chances of a response useful to them.

Comment: Possibly related: *[Meta tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info)*, *[Are meta tags banned across the board on all Stack Exchange sites or can each site decide if it wants to allow meta tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283907)*, and *[The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)* (blog post) - *"There are a few tags on Stack Overflow that have bugged me for a long time. Namely: subjective, best-practices, beginner"*

Comment: Any non-tag-based solution would require changes in the underlying infrastracture, and would thus need to be approved/implemented by SE CMs/developers (might be unlikely for something like this). Regarding tag-based solutions... isn't there already a version of this, in the form of [tag:homework-and-exercises], and [tag:research-level] on the other side of the spectrum?